# Accessing files from directory does not return fully qualified file paths

Tags: f#

Using F#, I am unable to retrieve the full paths of files within a directory.

I am using the following code:

```
module ProcessFiles

open System.IO

let getFiles directory= 
    seq { yield! Directory.GetFiles(directory) }

let files = getFiles @"C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlackJack\BlackJack\Assets\Cards"
            |> Seq.toArray
```

The output in my REPL window is as follows:

> ```
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[48 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[50 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[51 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[48 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[49 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[48 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[49 chars];
> "C:\Users\my_user_name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blac"+[42 chars
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your output shows full paths. What do you expect?

Comment: The REPL (FSI) truncates long strings when displaying them, in order to make the value listings more readable. The strings still have their full values.

Comment: You can add `|> Seq.iter (fun s -> printfn "%s" s)` and you'll see that array contains strings with full file paths

Comment: @Pert, `|> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")`